# New to WordPress - editing existing theme

Tags: php, wordpress, workflow

Forgive me if this isn't the right environment to pose a question of this nature.

I've just been assigned a project to create a site in WordPress based off of a purchased theme of similar structure. This is my first time working with WP, so I'm a bit overwhelmed with where to start.

I'm used to only working through a text editor, but WP obviously has a dev portal online that formatting and content can be built through.

So far I only have my theme imported and activated on WP and the PSDs for the site-to-be.

**Should I be doing my editing/formatting/content-building through this online portal? My text editor? A combination?**

Thanks in advance for any knowledge you can shed or articles you share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a paradigm shift moving from standard text editor web development into the world of WP. Here are some points to help you along:

- You should download/install a plugin called Synchi. This will make the WordPress text editor much more robust. It also allows you the ability to access and modify the WP theme files directly thru the dashboard (Appearance > Editor).
- You *can* use an external text editor and jump back and forth, but I find it easier to stay inside the WP dashboard once you have Synchi installed. I only use Visual Studio if I'm coding something more complex and I want to see Intellisense.
- If you are going to be making major changes to your base WP theme, you should create a "Child Theme" and work off of that. http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
- There are millions of articles on how to get started with WP, so I'll let you Bing/Google that. Just keep in mind there's a bit of a learning curve so just BE PATIENT - you'll figure it out quickly enough!

Comment: Thank you, Matt, this is incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about using the [Appearance Editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Editor_Screen), **use extreme caution**. If you mess up a `.php` file, you can blank your whole website:

> Be very careful editing PHP files of your current theme. The editor does not make backup copies. If you introduce an error that crashes your site, you cannot use the editor to fix the problem.

I would *strongly* recommend that you only use your text editor, and upload your changes to your WP server. Also, *make sure you have backups*, so that you can revert to a working copy if something goes wrong.

One article that I found on the topic:
[Editing your WordPress Site 101](http://www.carriedils.com/editing-wordpress-site-101/)

> Repeat with me: Never use the built-in WordPress file editor. I won't bore you with all the reasons the built-in editor is a bad idea, but here’s the #1 reason: *If you get a white screen of death, there's no way to access your site via wp-admin anymore.*

Comment: If I've misunderstood, and you're asking about WP's WYSIWYG editor, then by all means use the built-in WP one.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with the above response - you should avoid using the Wordpress editor for modifying theme files. Use the editor for creating pages and posts, only.

If you truly need to understand Wordpress, you should begin by understanding how it works. Unlike a static html site, Wordpress is created by a combination of php files which create parts of the final page (displayed to the user). Understanding the basics of how wordpress loads files will really help you get started. (tons of resources online)

Find a good text editor (or a free code editor like NetBeans), then learn how to sftp or ssh into your webserver so that you can edit theme files in your code editor.

Once you have that figured out, and understand how Wordpress loads files, you can begin modifying the theme to your PSDs, or create a child theme and do the same.

The point made by the above poster is quite valid... if you miss a  tag or some other php error causes a 'white screen of death', you'll not be able to load the wordpress editor (because it's broken) to fix it. Whereas with an sftp connection you can still modify the file, then push it back to the server and reaccess your admin editor.